# SqlPackager.exe excluding users in report

Tags: sql-server

Using SSDT 2012 I generate the following to determine the changes required between two databases and end up with Diff.xml

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /Action:Extract /SourceDatabaseName:MyDb_TestData /TargetFile:MyDb_TestData.dacpac /p:IgnoreExtendedProperties=True /p:IgnorePermissions=False /p:ExtractApplicationScopedObjectsOnly=True
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /Action:Extract /SourceDatabaseName:MyDb /TargetFile:MyDb.dacpac /p:IgnoreExtendedProperties=True /p:IgnorePermissions=False /p:ExtractApplicationScopedObjectsOnly=True

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:DeployReport /sf:MyDb.dacpac /tf:MyDb_TestData.dacpac /tdn:MyDb_TestData /op:Diff.xml
```

A snippet looks as follows:

[image]

however I don't want to include SQL Users in the comparison. However in the EXTRACT and REPORT actions there does not appear to be any way to exlude these (although PUBLISH does). Setting IgnorePermissions to FALSE also does not do the trick.

Is there any way to exclude users somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx#DeployReport Parameters and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx#DeployReport%20Parameters%20and%20Properties)

look into:

/p:DropObjectsNotInSource= {True | False}

/p:DoNotDropObjectType=Users

/p:ExcludeObjectType=users

/p:IgnoreUserSettingsObjects

Some combination of these will likely give you the Output you want.   Search that link for the specifics.   I had a very similar issue, in that SSDT Schema compare and SQLPackage.exe generated different results

Comment: The question I asked that helped me:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147087/sqlpackage-exe-not-picking-up-changes