# SqlPackager.exe what is SqlPermissionStatement?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SqlPackager to determine the changes between two databases as  [described here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156973/sqlpackager-exe-excluding-users-in-report)

What I cannot figure out is what the SqlPermissionStatement is referring to? Is it a byproduct of the missing user?

In other words I don't know how to make the change to my target database to make this disappear from the deployment report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I identify one reason of such entry in my project(SSDT).
I have following entry in code:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[up_Foo] TO [$(Domain)\$(DBUserName)] AS [dbo];
```

Then in Deployment script I can find this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[up_Foo] TO NULL AS [dbo];
```

And related:

```
<Operations>
    <Operation Name="Create">
        <Item Value="Permission" Type="SqlPermissionStatement" />
    </Operation>
</Operations>
```

Therefore I believe I have some problem with CMDVARs substitution. What generates grant execute to null. And grant execute to null is always interpreted as new grant.